# rotate and crop image then save that image on same path

Tags: android, image, crop, image-gallery

I am able to see rotated and croped image in full screen mode but somehow it does not update in thumbnail part.

1)I have select one image from gallery and display in recyclerview wich contains imageview.
2)Then i click on imageview which open in fullscreen and do rotation and cropping then save that image with cropper library
3)Then it does not get updated in recyclerview but when i click on that image then it display croped and rotated image in fullscreen mode.

I want to display image same as full screen mode in my recyclerview

Below is my code...

```
  //override method for cropper library
 @Override
 public void onCropImageComplete(CropImageView view,CropImageView.CropResult result) { 

    handleCropResult(result, view);
}

      private void handleCropResult(CropImageView.CropResult result, CropImageView view) 
    {
    if (result.getError() == null) {
        view.setImageBitmap(view.getCroppedImage());
        saveImageInGallery(view.getCroppedImage(),         String.valueOf(view.getTag()));
        Log.i("UriResult", String.valueOf(result.getUri()));
    } else {
        Log.e("AIC", "Failed to crop image", result.getError());
        Toast.makeText(_activity, "Image crop failed: " + result.getError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}



  private void saveImageInGallery(Bitmap bitmap, String imagePath) {
    File file = new File(imagePath);
    if (file.exists()) {
        if (file.delete()) {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            _activity.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
    }

    try {
        File mNewFile = new File(imagePath);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mNewFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        bitmap.recycle();


        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(mNewFile);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        _activity.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: this may help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458

Comment: do you go to another activity for rotating?

Comment: @masoudvali yes sir.

Answer (score 0):

in onResume section of your activity call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: if your list in not too long just create another object of adapter in onResume

Answer (score 0):

I have previously display image with glide and right now i replace it with

holder.imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://" +  imageList.get(position).getImageName()));

its works now.